# How to load list of another table in one2many popup form to add it to main form in odoo 12?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-view, odoo-12

how to load list in another table in one2many popup form in odoo 12? I try to create an invoice module, which is I have 2 custom module,
1. invoice module
2. master product

Here is my produk.py (model) :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class ProdukProduk(models.Model):
    _name = 'ms_produk.ms_produk'

    kd_produk = fields.Char(String='Kode Produk', required=True)
    nm_produk = fields.Char(String='Nama Produk', required=True)
    tanggal_input = fields.Datetime(string='Tanggal Input', default=fields.Datetime.now())
    tanggal_aktif = fields.Datetime(string='Tanggal Aktif', default=fields.Datetime.now())
    status_aktif = fields.Boolean('Status Aktif', default=True)
    keterangan = fields.Html(string='Keterangan')
```

and here is my invoice module part, I have this salesorder.py model :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class SalesorderSalesorder(models.Model):
    _name = 'salesorder.salesorder'

    no_faktur = fields.Char(String='No Faktur', required=True)
    kd_dealer = fields.Char(String='Kode Dealer', required=True)
    nm_dealer = fields.Char(String='Nama Dealer', required=True)
    tanggal_faktur = fields.Datetime(string='Tgl Faktur', default=fields.Datetime.now())
    keterangan = fields.Html(string='Keterangan')
    kd_sales = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Kode Sales')
    details = fields.One2many('salesorderdetails','no_faktur','List Item')
```

and salesorderdetails.py (model) :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class SalesOrderDetails(models.Model):
    _name = 'salesorderdetails'

    kd_produk = fields.Char(String='Kode Produk', required=True)
    nm_produk = fields.Char(String='Nama Produk', required=True)
    qty = fields.Integer(String='Qty', required=True)
    harga = fields.Float(String='Nama Produk', required=True)
    no_faktur = fields.Many2one('salesorder.salesorder')
```

It worked, but I need to add a line popup view to load the list of my product, so I can pick a product to add to the salesorderdetails line, how do I do this? I do not know where to start to add some value in the popup view.

This is how it showed up with my code up there :

[image]

Here is what I want it looks like, this photo below I photoshop it :

[image]

so I can pick the item and add it to the salesorderdetails table, how do I accomplish this?

UPDATED with terrace poe answer, here is my salesorder_view.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>

        <record id="salesorder_menu_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">SalesOrders</field>
            <field name="res_model">salesorder.salesorder</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create SalesOrders
                </p>
            </field>
        </record>

<!-- newly added -->

        <!-- main salesorder list-->
        <record id="salesorder_list" model="ir.ui.view" >
            <field name="name">salesorder list</field>
            <field name="model">salesorder.salesorder</field>
            <field name="type">tree</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="List SO">
                    <field name="no_faktur"/>
                    <field name="nm_dealer"/>
                    <field name="kd_dealer"/>
                    <field name="tanggal_faktur"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        <!-- end of main salesorder list-->

        <!-- salesorder view -->
        <record id="salesorder_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">salesorder.form.tree</field>
            <field name="model">salesorder.salesorder</field>
            <field name="type">tree</field>
            <field name='arch' type="xml">
                <field name='details'>
                    <tree string="SalesOrder" editable="bottom">
                        <field name="kd_produk"/>
                        <field name="nm_produk"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
        <!-- end of salesorder view -->

        <!-- details -->
        <record id="detail_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">sodetails</field>
            <field name="model">salesorderdetails</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree>
                    <field name="kd_produk"/>
                    <field name="nm_produk"/>
                    <field name="qty"/>
                    <field name="harga"/>
                    <field name='item_ids'>
                        <tree>
                            <field name='kd_produk'/>
                            <field name='nm_produk'/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </tree>
            </field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="salesorder_tree"/>
            <field name="act_window_id" ref="salesorder_menu_action"/>
        </record>
        <!-- end of details -->

        <!-- master product view -->
        <!-- <record id="browse_msproduk_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">ms_produk</field>
            <field name="model">ms_produk.ms_produk</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree editable="bottom">
                    <field name="kd_produk"/>
                    <field name="nm_produk"/>
                    <field name="tanggal_input"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="salesorder_tree"/>
            <field name="act_window_id" ref="salesorder_menu_action"/>
        </record> -->
        <!-- end of master product view -->

<!-- end of newly added -->

        <menuitem id="salesorder_menu" name="SalesOrder"/>
        <menuitem id="Salesorder_neworder_menu" 
                parent="salesorder_menu" 
                name="New Order"
                action="salesorder_menu_action"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

and here is my salesorderdetails.py looked like :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api

class SalesOrderDetails(models.Model):
    _name = 'salesorderdetails'
    # _inherit = 'salesorder.salesorder'

    kd_produk = fields.Char(String='Kode Produk', required=True)
    nm_produk = fields.Char(String='Nama Produk', required=True)
    qty = fields.Integer(String='Qty', required=True)
    harga = fields.Float(String='Nama Produk', required=True)
    no_faktur = fields.Many2one('salesorder.salesorder')
    # just added
    item_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='ms_produk.ms_produk')
    # end of just added
```

it worked, but not the result i want, now it looked like this :

[image]

i don't want to fill the other column, i just want to pick the item and add it to salesorderdetails table, it seems like i add my product to salesorderdetail column named item, should be look like my edited image one. I need to add kd_produk and nm_produk value from ms_product.ms_product to kd_produk and nm_produk in salesorderdetails

[image]

this one

Comment: you want to show list of `ProdukProduk` in salesorderdetails, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`you want to show list of ProdukProduk in salesorderdetails, right?`
If it is true, set a m2m field in salesorderdetails. like

```py
class SalesOrderDetails(models.Model):
    _name = 'salesorderdetails'

    kd_produk = fields.Char(String='Kode Produk', required=True)
    nm_produk = fields.Char(String='Nama Produk', required=True)
    qty = fields.Integer(String='Qty', required=True)
    harga = fields.Float(String='Nama Produk', required=True)
    no_faktur = fields.Many2one('salesorder.salesorder')
    item_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='ms_produk.ms_produk')
```

then you should add item_ids in salesorderdetails's form view.

```xml
<field name='item_ids'>
    <tree>
        <field name='field1_in_ms_produk.ms_produk'>
        <field name='field2_in_ms_produk.ms_produk'>
    </tree>
</field>
```

you can see view like this
[image]

And if you can not find that template in odoo directory, try to modified it directly by developer mode.
[image]

Comment: hi terrence poe, i already update my code with your answer, but its not the result i want, it looked like, can u help me take a look and my edited screenshot one?

Comment: Do you mean you want that item_ids fields can display products as second pic you posted? (the pic I can see there are 3 products.)?

Comment: And the product list that you want to display is default way or custom way?

Comment: If it's a default way, `item_ids` field attach `default=lambda self:self.env['ms_produk.ms_produk'].search([])' maybe can be the answer.

Comment: If you want ask further question, enter this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195957/chat). If I have free I'll answer you.

Comment: hi terrence poe, i try use comodel= in many2many parameter, it give me strange error, then i delete the comodel= word, and its worked. Thanks terrence

Comment: yes, it's my fault. should be `comodel_name`. sorry for that.

Comment: hi @Terrence Poe, i have another question again, can u help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386876/how-to-bind-value-from-one2many-dropdown-data-to-column-field-in-odoo-12